# tools:replace does not work

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to use **android:allowBackup=false**, but some other libraries have **android:allowBackup=true**.

So I need to add **tools:replace="android:allowBackup"**, and this is also the way the **Manifest Merger** suggests, BUT it **does not work**.

After compile and also in the Manifest Merger Tool I get again **the same error**.
The tools:replace is already set, but the Manifest Merge suggests to add it.

If I click on the suggestion it will add another tools:replace tag.

Here is the Manifest Merger error:
[image: Manifest Merger]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be caused by a bug in the Gradle plugin: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193679
If you remove the tools:ignore attribute from the application element, it should work.

Comment: Seems you're right, but if I remove the tools:ignore it does not work :-( I think I have to wait until 2.3 is released. Anayway thanks for pointing me to this bug report.